How to do a hidden input in MATLAB for a password
I would like to have an account system in mathlab. I write here because to insert the password I have used the normal text-input. But I would like to have a way to write a hidden input that doesn't show what I write, just like other password inputs on other websites.
Thanks!
Hidden input for password

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20400-encryption-of-password#answer_27002
